# Sonata Media Bundle ftp connection configuration?

Tags: php, symfony, ftp, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I am trying to configure Sonata Media Bundle ftp connection:

```
sonata_media:
    filesystem:
        ftp:
            directory: /path-to-upload
            host:      http://ftp-server-host
            username:  username
            password:  password
            port:      21
            passive:   false
            create:    true
            mode:      2
```

But when I upload a file nothing happens. The ftp server log does not show any connection request. Isn't it enough to just make the configuration for ftp connection in yml file? And under the filesystem parameter I only have ftp parameter, no local or any other parameter is configured.

Comment: You have to add the answer in the appropriate area and not inside the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

Sonata Media providers default filesystem are `sonata.media.filsytem.local`.

I just had to add this to provider

```
sonata_media:
     providers:
         file:
             filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.ftp
```